# How to obtain the public key hash in on chain plutus validator?

Tags: plutus, on-chain, public-key

It seems public key hash is generated from blake2b_224 but in on-chain validator we only have blake2b_256. Is there any way to obtain public key hash from public key in cardano plutus?